SharePoint List Error: Try again (There has been an error while loading the form)
I submitted new request in SharePoint list and the workflow running correctly, if I try to open the task to approve it I have error.
The error what I have

and this pic for my task
When I click on task to open it

I used customize form by using InfoPath 2013, before 2 week everything working correctly but now I have this issue, and I have many site I use custom form by InfoPath and I don't face this issue.
I try to republished the form again and workflow but still.

Infopath retirement was announced over ten years ago. If you're still using InfoPath, maybe you should really, really be thinking about moving to a different platform.

Yeah, but still in my work they used InfoPath
